# Parse and print JSON

Tags: debian, printing, json

I have created a web application that serves order list information in JSON format everytime I access an URL like: http://www.domain.com/order/list.

Then I want my Raspberry Pi to parse the JSON and print a order receipt based on the parsed JSON data.

**Here is a way I think I could do it:**

1. Install CUPS print system and PHP
2. Use `wget` (or `cURL` in PHP) to fetch the data and write to a file e.g. orders.json.
3. Use PHP to read the file, parse the JSON and write a file for each order e.g. `1001.txt`, `1002.txt`.
4. Use `lpr` command to send the each order file to the printer.
5. Setup a cron job to do the process every 5 minutes.

What is missing is to everytime a print job is successful the web application should be notified. Maybe after running `lpr` I can somehow find out if it was successful and run a `wget` command with the URL http://www.domain.com/order/success/1001. After that the file `1001.txt` should be deleted.

**Do you have a better solution?**

Example JSON:

```
[{
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Peter Smith",
    "products": ["Burger", "Fries", "Soda"]
}, {
    "id": 1002,
    "name": "Don Johnson",
    "products": ["Burger", "Fries", "Soda"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm..  you may want to check [cURL](http://codular.com/curl-with-php) out . I think that would be easier in combination with GET :-)